# CSS background scrolling effects

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a website where the hero/header is divided into two parts, a left site with information, and a right side with a graphic. The right side (image) is supposed to have a simple parallax effect, so I gave it `background-attachment: fixed;`.

Now, I'm supposed to change the `background-attachment` property when the bottom of the graphic hits the next section, so the picture'll scroll upwards with the rest of the text from then on.

Here's a Fiddle that might make my intentions a bit more clear.

https://jsfiddle.net/fg67ho2L/1/

Is there any way to make this happen so the right side (image) behaves as expected? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is change the `height` property of your right side so that it's less then left side if you want to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

The script gives me an error, so I changed

```
var abouttop = document.getElementById("about").getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

THen I decided not to use `background-attachment` but `transforms`.
Additionally, you are missing the `id="about"` to your text-container.
I don't use JQuery so here is some working js (sorry for the mess):

```
var pos = 0;

var imageControl = function(e) {
  var scrollposition = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var abouttop = document.getElementById("about").getBoundingClientRect().height;
  var scrollBottom = jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height();
  var image_height = document.getElementById("image").getBoundingClientRect().height;
  // console.log(scrollBottom);

  if (scrollBottom < abouttop) {
    pos = scrollposition;
  } else if (scrollBottom > abouttop) {
    //pos = abouttop-image_height;
  }
  console.log(pos);
  document.getElementById("image").style.transform = "translateY(" + pos + "px)";
};

jQuery(window).scroll(imageControl);
```